# Access class from inside included module

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to do this:

```
class IncludingClass
  include IncludedModule
end

module IncludedModule
  self.parent_class # => IncludingClass, I wish
end
```

Any ideas? Sorry for the brevity. Typing this on a phone. At any rate, I've looked around and haven't been able to find this, which seems surprising for such a met aprogrammable language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe modules keep track of what included them.  But they do fire a `MyModule.included(SomeClass)` method as a callback when they get included, so you can keep track yourself.

```
module IncludedModule

  # Array to store included classes
  @@included_classes = []

  # Called when this module is included.
  # The including class is passed as an argument.
  def self.included(base)
    @@included_classes << base
  end

  # Getter for class variable
  def self.included_classes
    @@included_classes
  end
end

# Include the module
class IncludingClass
  include IncludedModule
end

# Ask the module what included it.
puts IncludedModule.included_classes #=> [IncludingClass]
```

---

There's probably also a way to crawl all Classes declared and ask them what they included via `SomeClass.included_modules` but that's kind of hairy, and would be much slower.

Comment: Well that's really cool. Not sure it'll work in my case, but it's an interesting solution. Thanks!