# Constantize raises Uninitialized Constant Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm working on [this pretty thorny problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674714/creating-a-module-for-raising-class-specific-errors) and decided I might be able to dynamically create a class that inherits from StandardError by doing this:

```
something = "JustForBelow"
error_class = "#{something}Error".constantize
error_class = StandardError.new
```

But I'm getting a really weird error (in my opinion), which is:

```
Uninitialized constant JustForBelowError
```

Aren't I initializing it right there?

(Essentially) same error comes up when I try this:

```
StandardError.const_get "#{something}Error"
# => NameError: uninitialized constant StandardError::JustForBelowClass
```

This feels really weird, because a) these are super random names; there aren't any conflicts, and b) I'm pretty sure I've used constantize like in the first example before. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveSupport's `constantize` method just looks up a constant. It's a fancier version of `const_get` that does nice things like traverse a nested module structure.

To create a new error, you'll want to do something like this:

```
2.0.0-p247 :013 > Object.const_set("MyNewError", Class.new(StandardError))
 => MyNewError
2.0.0-p247 :014 > MyNewError.ancestors
 => [MyNewError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

At which point, you can do `"MyNewError".constantize` and get back that new class object.

**Edit**
Also note that `const_get` in your second example error is looking inside the namespace it was called on.  In that case, inside of `StandardError`'s scope.

For instance, if you have a class structure like:

```
module A
  class B
    CONSTANT = "hello world"
  end
end
```

Then you could get at that with `"A::B::CONSTANT".constantize`, or by doing `Object.const_get("A").const_get("B").const_get("CONSTANT")`.  Same thing, just ActiveSupport made is smoother to do.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that is trying to find, "How can I constantize when the class may not exist", there is `safe_constantize`, which will return `nil` if the class does not exist. It's essentially just a `rescue` around `constantize`.

```
'blargle'.safe_constantize  # => nil
'UnknownModule'.safe_constantize  # => nil
'UnknownModule::Foo::Bar'.safe_constantize  # => nil
```

[safe_constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/safe_constantize)

Answer (score 1):

You would have initialised it if you had done this:

```
class JustForBelowError < StandardError ; end
something = "JustForBelow"
error_class = "#{somestring}Error".constantize
error_class = StandardError.new
```

You need to define a constant if you want to be able to "access" it using `constantize`.

Comment: So is there no way to define that constant dynamically? As in, without knowing exactly what string will take the place of JustForBelowError, to initialize that class from an interpolated string?

Comment: Wait. Just saw the above, which seems to answer that follow-up